# How to access Visual Studio 2019 report designer?

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework-6, report, designer

Recently had need to edit some existing reports and have not been able to access the report designer in Visual Studio 2019.  My application is WPF using SQLite and Entity Framework in C#.  I haven't had to work with reports in a couple of years and don't have good notes from the original development.  App, including reports, runs fine.

Recently upgraded to Visual Studio 16.3.0 Preview 2.0.  Have SSDT included.   Installed Reporting Service Projects 2.5.9.  Have run Repair on VS 2019.

Perhaps need a reporting services project?  Sorry don't have good notes from original development.

Comment: You need to install the extension, and add a reporting services project